# How to do connection pooling with ZeroMQ and PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, connection-pooling, zeromq, php

Excuse me for perhaps lame question, I'm C++ guy.

Could you please explain to me how I can efficiently support lots of ZeroMQ php clients?

I'm using nginx with php-fpm on RedHat server.

Consider I have following code in `client.php` which is served to thousands of web-clients

```
$client = new ZMQSocket($context,ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
$client->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
$client->send($sequence);
```

Does it mean that given code will reconnect to zeromq server on every http request ? It looks horribly inefficient to me. Is there connection pooling with ZeroMQ and PHP-FPM ?

How should I do it properly ?

PS. After reading documentation [ZMQContext::getSocket](http://php.zero.mq/zmqcontext.getsocket.html) looks like candidate where pooling may be, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it means on every request - you'd reconnect. If you want to scale your ZMQ+PHP setup, you should get [Mongrel2](http://www.mongrel2.org) and create a worker in PHP, which alleviates the need for FPM, which in turn allows you to horizontally scale by plugging in more workers - after which mongrel directs requests to each using round-robin system. There's a great example and framework ready called [Photon](http://www.photon-project.com/) which works surprisingly fast and it's efficient, but it's not fully optimized (yet it's still fast).

Comment: @N.B. Thank you for detailed comment. What would you suggest if I can't switch from nginx yet? What if I run 0mq server written in C on the same box which will be listening on Unix Domain socket and php client will connect to it on each http request? I don't what the cost of establishing connection with Unix Domain sockets. I suspect it's cheap.

Comment: `php` is a [`CGI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)-like language in general. You should look for something like [Python](http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/), Ruby, etc..

Comment: If you run the C server, you either have to implement event loop or threads for managing the connected clients, which is what your underlying server does initially. You can give it a shot, however from my experience - creating a daemon in language of your choice that restarts itself after 100 or so requests was the best option, so you can keep the codebase based on a single language. @VBart - you're spreading misinformation, please don't do it unless you're 100% certain you're correct about the info you're posting.

Comment: @N.B. It's 100% correct.

Comment: @VBart - you're not correct, especially not in this matter, please don't post incorrect information.

Comment: @N.B. Could you please post your answer below so I can accept it ?